# How to pass vue component props array of object?

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a dropdown in my component and here is a json file that comes from back:

```
items:[
        {
           name:"label",
           value:"",
           options:[
              
           ]
        },
        {
           name:"hint_text",
           value:"",
           options:[
              
           ]
        },
        {
           name:"icon",
           value:"",
           options:[
              
           ]
        },
        {
           name:"selectableOptions",
           value:[
              {
                 id:"1",
                 text:"item1",
              },
              {
                 id:"2",
                 text:"item2",
                 image_url:null
              },
              {
                 id:"3",
                 text:"item3",
                 image_url:null
              },
              {
                 id:"4",
                 text:"item4",
                 image_url:null
              },
              {
                 id:"5",
                 text:"item5",
                 image_url:null
              },
              {
            ]
}
]
```

and this is how my component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="field">
            <v-select
                label="Label" // label must be eqau to items[0].name
                hint="hint"//hint must be equal items[1].name
                persistent-hint
                background-color=""
                :items="['item1', 'item2', 'item3']"// must be equal to items[3].value.text
                outlined
            >
                <span
                    class=""
                    style="font-size:16px; color:#000000;"
                    slot="prepend-inner"
                >icon</span>// must be equal to item[2].name
            </v-select>
        </div>
    <script>
      export default {
         props: {
             items: {
                  type: Object;
         },
      };
   </script>
```

I got an error that items is not Object and it's an array but if I change to an array still doesn't work. and would you please help me, How to pass properly the items' elements which I write in the comments part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not fully correct and there's something wrong with template code, but I hope it's just typos.

You can just set correct type of your prop (it should be an **Array**) and you'll be able to pass array of props this way:

```
...
<div class="dropdown">
    <div>
        <v-select
            :label="items[0].name" 
            :hint="items[1].name"
            persistent-hint
            background-color=""
            :items="items[3].value"
            item-value="id"
            item-text="text"
            outlined
        >
            <span
                class=""
                style="font-size:16px; color:#000000;"
                slot="prepend-inner"
            > {{ items[2].name }} </span>
        </v-select>
    </div>
</div>
...
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            items: {
                type: Array
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if I want to add v-model what should I pass to it according to json file?

Comment: @AtousaDehsarvi It depends on your goals. I guess, you need to store item's id (items[3].value.id), as it now declared by item-value prop. If you need to store the whole object instead of its id, you can remove `item-value=...` and add `return-object` prop

Answer (score 0):

For people looking this up in 2024 using vue3.3+ with typescript:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<{
    arrayOfObjects: { someNum: number, someStr: string }[]
}>()

</script>
```

More about it [HERE](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#type-only-props-emit-declarations)